# Ajax Webpage Not Displaying Most Update to Date Content After Redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have page that displays images from different directories and can change the file names of files in a folder, based on their order in a jQuery sortable list.

So far everything is working except that after I Save the new file names and the Save page redirects to the Edit page I have to do a "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" in order for the new file order to be displayed.

Edit Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION['username']) {
    echo "<script>window.location = './index.php'</script>";
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="../js/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(window).load(function() {
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#btnRefresh").click(function() {
                        window.location.reload(true);
                    });
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'getPics.php',
                        success: function(resultOfAjaxCall) {
                            xmlDoc = $.parseXML(resultOfAjaxCall);
                            $xml = $(xmlDoc);
                            html = "";
                            $xml.find('Folder').each(function(index) {
                                //console.log($(this).attr('Name'));
                                city = $(this).attr('Name');
                                html += "<h3 class='accordion-header'>" + city + "</h3>";
                                html += "<div class='accordion-section'>";
                                html += "<button id='" + city + "_Save'>Save " + city + "</button>";
                                html += "    ";
                                //Upload Form
                                html += '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">';
                                html += '<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />';
                                html += '<input type="hidden" name="City_Folder" value="' + city + '" />';
                                html += 'Choose a file to upload: <input name="userfile" type="file" /><br />';
                                html += '<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />';
                                html += '</form>';
                                //Save Form
                                html += '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="save.php" method="POST" id="' + city + '_Save_Form">';
                                html += '<input type="hidden" name="City_Folder" value="' + city + '" />';
                                html += '</form>';
                                html += "<ul class='" + city + "-sortable-list'>";
                                $(this).find('File').each(function(index) {
                                    //console.log($(this).text()
                                    fileName = $(this).find('File_Name').text();
                                    filePath = $(this).find('File_Path').text();
                                    fileRealPath = $(this).find('File_Real_Path').text();
                                    //console.log(fileName);
                                    //console.log(filePath);
                                    html += '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="delete.php" method="POST" id="' + fileName + '_Delete_Form">';
                                    html += '<input type="hidden" name="Delete_Path" value="' + filePath + '" />';
                                    html += '</form>'
                                    html += "<li id='" + fileName + "' class='ui-state-default' value='" + fileRealPath + "'>" + fileName + "    ";
                                    html += "<button id='" + fileName + "_Delete'>Delete</button>";
                                    html += "<br>"
                                    html += "<img src='" + filePath + "' style='width:150px;'/>";
                                    html += "<br></li>";
                                })
                                html += "</ul>";
                                html += "</div>";
                                //window.location.reload(true);
                            });
                            $("#accordion").append(html);
                            var $accordion = $("#accordion").accordion({
                                collapsible: true,
                                heightStyle: "content",
                                active: false
                            });
                            $("[class$=-sortable-list]").sortable({
                                update: function(event, ui) {
                                    console.log(ui);
                                    var order = [];
                                    $("[class$=-sortable-list] li").each(function(e) {
                                        order.push($(this).attr("id") + "=" + ($(this).index() + 1));
                                    });
                                    var positions = order.join();
                                    //        alert(positions);
                                },
                                stop: function(event, ui) {
                                    console.log("an item was moved");
                                    $accordion.find("#tmp").remove();
                                },
                                start: function(event, ui) {
                                    $accordion.append("<ul id='tmp'></ul>");
                                            $accordion.find("#tmp").append(ui.item);
                                }
                            }).disableSelection();


                            //Save Click   
                            $("[id$=_Save_Form]").submit(function(event) {
                                folder = event.target.id.replace("_Save_Form", "");
                                $("." + folder + "-sortable-list li").each(function(e) {
                                    //alert(folder);
                                    //alert($(this).index());
                                    //alert($(this).attr("value"));
                                    $("<input />").attr("type", "hidden")
                                            .attr("name", "path[" + $(this).index() + "]")
                                            .attr("value", $(this).attr("value"))
                                            .appendTo("#" + event.target.id);
                                });

                            });
                            $("[id$=_Save]").click(function(event) {
                                $("#" + event.target.id + "_Form").submit();
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
        <title>Edit Slider</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php ?>
        <p>You are logged in as <?= $_SESSION['username'] ?> (<a href="./index.php?logout=1">Logout</a>)</p>
        <p><button id="btnRefresh">Refresh</button></p>

        <div id="accordion">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Save Page

```
<?php
$root = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, "DOCUMENT_ROOT", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES);
require $root . '/CC_Library/CC_Folder.php';
require $root . '/CC_Library/CC_String.php';
$folder = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "City_Folder", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES);
$dir = "";
$i = 0;
$s = new CC_String;
$tmp = $s->generate_rand(5);
foreach ($_POST['path'] as $value) {
    $CC = new CC_File($value);
    $dir = $CC->get_File_Dir();

    echo "Changing " . $CC->get_Full_File_Name() . " to " . $tmp . str_pad($i, 10, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . "." . $CC->get_File_Extension() . "<br>";
    $CC->Rename($tmp . str_pad($i, 10, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . "." . $CC->get_File_Extension());
    $i++;
}
$j = 0;
//echo $dir;
$F = new CC_Folder($dir);
$Files = $F->get_Folder_Files();
foreach ($Files as $value) {
    echo "Changing " . $value->get_Full_File_Name() . " to " . $folder . "-" . str_pad($j, 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . "." . $value->get_File_Extension() . "<br>";
    $value->Rename($folder . "-" . str_pad($j, 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . "." . $value->get_File_Extension());
    $j++;
}
echo "<script>window.location.replace('Edit_Slider.php')</script>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont want to read all of that notorious code. Your problem is client sided, not server sided so your code is irreverent.
Your webbrowser is caching and not updating your images. A fix for this would be to extend the current image source  with a timestamp like so:

```
<img src="image.jpg?lastmod=12345678"
```

//javascript

```
function(img_src){
     var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
     img_src += "lastmod?" + timestamp;
}
```

[how to clear or replace a cached image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321865/how-to-clear-or-replace-a-cached-image)

The reason this works is because the source URL is different each time because of the timestamp will always be different & web browsers remember content relative to the URL.