# jQuery Magnify image will not rotate in Chrome only?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the jQuery Magnify plugin. The image doesn't rotate in Chrome unless I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

After rotation I tried `window.location.reload(true)`, random query string on JS files, using the following `meta` tags in the document:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

On click rotate button:

```
$.post("" + document.getElementById('site_url').value + "project_management/rotate_image", {
  src: $image[0].src, 
  angle: angle,
  direction: direction
}).done(function(data) {
  window.location.reload(true);
});
```

The image rotates on the backend but is not shown on the screen after reloading.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />

Comment: why don't you return the rotated image in your ajax call and simply swap it with the one currently on the page?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/321875/1906356 if you want to disable cache on images

Comment: Thanks for your reply but query string doesn't work for me.

Comment: I already try this <img src="<?php echo base_url($file->full_path); ?>?=<?php echo rand() . "\n";?>" alt="">

Comment: return post back data and replace but not working still Crlt+F5 required to show rotation.$('#replace_html').html(data);
    window.location.reload(true);

Answer (score 0):

So Query string does the trick in Manigfy.Js Thanks you very much madalinivascu