# Cache problem on changing <img> src attr with same file name

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, src

i'm trying changing dinamically the src path of a img tag

i have:

```
<img src="img1.jpg">
```

Then i upload new photo by iframe and new photo takes the same name (img1.jpg) then by ajax i refresh the src path (which is the same but photo is changed)

The problem is that i use same file name, img doesn't change in browser, guessing cause of browser cache...

Is there any jquery,html or php solution on this?

thanks

Comment: You could try appending a random query string to the end... img src="img1.jpg?random_string"

Comment: Try changing the image to something temporary while it is uploaded, and then switch the src back to the img1.jpg. If that doesnt work, consider using a different image name.

Comment: @AllisonC your comment should really be an answer instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728616/disable-cache-for-some-images

Comment: @allison  yep Peer is right, your is really an answer and also right answer ;) it works! thx ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try appending a random query string to the end... img src="img1.jpg?random_string"

Answer (score 2):

You could return the image as a base64 string in the ajax response, and append the data to the img element.

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,[STRING GOES HERE]" alt=""/>
```

This way you will save another request. However, the base64-encoding means a few more bytes are transferred.

Comment: Naww, that's harsh :) You're correct, of course, I should have mentioned that. Thanks.

Comment: still... this is a nice approach! (Y)

Answer (score 1):

Its been cache issue.To resolve this issue use Math.random() as query param

```
<img src="url_goes_here?Math.random()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way if you don't want to use random as I feel might have a slight performance issue is:-

```
<img src="url_goes_here?(new Date).(new Date).getMilliseconds()" />
```