# Why filename.php.jpg will work as a PHP file?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to execute PHP with extension file.php.jpg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025236/is-it-possible-to-execute-php-with-extension-file-php-jpg)

I accidentally left a fileupload to my site, and it got hacked (STUPID ME). The hacker had uploaded a file index.php.jpg with the uploader, and simply accessed my site (it was a shell99 script) with it, but I can't understand why it will work. Someone smart enough to explain  this?

Comment: Is the file named `index.php.jpg` or `index.jpg.php`?

Comment: Because in fact _nobody_ is interested in a file extension ;) it is just a hint on what _may_ be inside the file, but nothing more.

Comment: If it was a .php you are a silly monkey :P

Comment: [Is it possible to execute PHP with extension file.php.jpg?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025236/is-it-possible-to-execute-php-with-extension-file-php-jpg)

Comment: @KingCrunch this would be perfect, but it is not true. Using "extension" is much faster that checking file magic bytes, so HTTP relies on that.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com Oh ... HTTP is just a "stupid" protocol, that doesn't even rely on files :D A webserver _may_ rely on it, because it is configured to do so (by you or a hacker, or whoever). It's always a human (namely: an admin), that tells the machine to rely on it.

Comment: @KingCrunch I meant `httpd` not `HTTP` as I wrote. Not sure does not by default rely on extension, but I think most would as it is just faster.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apache controls what file extensions can and cannot execute PHP. This can be controlled on a server-level, or a per-site level (such as with `.htaccess`).

By default, a `.jpg` extension should *not* allow PHP execution. Perhaps the filename was really `index.jpg.php` and you have misread. However, in the event that the filename is *really* `index.php.jpg`, you'll need to look into all possible locations and lock-down your configuration to only allow `.php` extensions to execute PHP.

Comment: It was index.php.jpg, because the script only accepted files with extensions .jpg or .png. I don't have the site on a server that I own, so I don't have access to the apache config, so I'll ask this from the server owner-

Answer (score 3):

Filename was either forged, with \x000 inserted which fooled httpd, or `.htaccess` was planted as well to enforce PHP for jpg files.

Comment: Interesting. How this works exactly? And how can be avoided?

Comment: Please, can you explain me what you mean with \x000.