# how to execute jpg or other extensions like php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to execute only one or two jpg files like php in a folder.

forexample
`www/folder/index.jpg` should run and shown like `www/folder/index.php`
or 
`www/folder/index.php` should run and shown `like www/folder/index.jpg` but it should work as php and it should shown as jpg

and other jpg files should run it is own name 
`www/folder/photo.jpg` > `www/folder/photo.jpg`

Comment: What are you hoping to do within `index.php`?

Comment: I think you need to reword your question. You can't execute a JPG file - it's an image, not a program. I can't work out from your question what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Is it stand in good stead?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399049/how-to-execute-jpg-or-other-extensions-like-php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025236/is-it-possible-to-execute-php-with-extension-file-php-jpg#answer-8025252

Comment: Image or other programs. I wanna execute them like php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't execute JPEG files per se, but you can have them be a PHP script that generates JPEG data to use in e.g. a `<img>` tag.

You need to set the handler for the file to `application/x-httpd-php`, output a content type of `image/jpeg` in the script, and, most importantly, **output JPEG data**. Might want to consider naming it `<something>.jpg.php` so you don't have to do the first one though, since that's server configuration.

Comment: But It is not for all jpg files. Only one or two files work like php. Other jpg files should work image too

Comment: So what. Only set the handler for those files. `AddHandler` is valid in a `<Files>` section.