# Dynamic SVG and other formats using PHP. Keep the extension?

Tags: php, svg

I'm interested in generating dynamic SVG images using PHP. Can I accomplish this without switching to the ".php" file extension for the source document? Can the source document have an ".svg" extension?

This tutorial seems to imply that the file *must* have an ".php" extension.

http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/37004

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to execute PHP with extension file.php.jpg?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025236/is-it-possible-to-execute-php-with-extension-file-php-jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual (on the disk) php file **must** have **.php** extension. This is required for it to be properly executed.

However, that doesn't mean that you have to use the file's filename in order to access it over the web. In Apache2 server, this is done using **mod_rewrite**. Read about it [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708).

> Example (taken from article):
>
> http://example.com/user.php?id=AHHHHHH
>
> http://example.com/user/AHHHHHH

Same way you can use it to "hide" `dynamic_svg.php` and make the url `dynamic.svg`

P.S. I used Apache2 as example, because it's the most popular server. Other web servers (nginx, IIS) have their own way of accomplishing this