# Unable to retrieve latest pic from PHP

Tags: php, image

I am using following code to store images on my webserver:

```
function SavePic()
{
    $allowedExts = array("jpeg", "jpg");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["UserPic"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);

    if ((($_FILES["UserPic"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["UserPic"]["type"] == "image/jpg"))
    //&& ($_FILES["UserPic"]["size"] < 2097152)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
        if ($_FILES["UserPic"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            echo json_encode("Error: ".$_FILES["UserPic"]["error"]);
        }
        else
        {    
            $folder = "/home5/username/public_html/Project/Users/Images/";                
            echo move_uploaded_file($_FILES["UserPic"]["tmp_name"],$folder.$_REQUEST["email"].".".$extension);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo json_encode("Invalid file");
    }
}
```

And Following code to retrieve image:

```
function RetrievePic()
{
    $handle = fopen('php://input','r');
    $jsonInput = fgets($handle);
    // Decoding JSON into an Array
    $retrieveParameters = json_decode($jsonInput,true);        

    $UserPic = array("UserPic" => "http://www.mysite.com/Project/Users/Images/".$retrieveParameters['email']."."."jpg");
    echo json_encode($UserPic);
}
```

For Example if my email is abc@xyz.com then image will be stored as "abc@xyz.com.jpg". The problem is that when I try to overwrite image in order to replace old one with new one, server is returning old one everytime.

**Update:**
When I place url in browser e.g http://www.mysite.com/Project/Users/Images/abc@xyz.com.jpg
latest image is shown and after that I start receiving latest image.

Comment: You might want to look at how the webserver is caching your data, you can always add a timestamp to the url (maybe file modified time?) `http://www.mysite.com/Project/Users/Images/abc@xyz.com.jpg?modifiedtime`

Comment: Just like @hank has just written: try `$UserPic = array("UserPic" => "http://www.mysite.com/Project/Users/Images/".$retrieveParameters['email']."."."jpg?".time());`

Comment: @MarcinKrawiec using `time()` will force a reload every time, which is a waste of bandwidth, better to use the actual modified time of the file.

Comment: @hank yup, you're right. Btw: @ChampTaurus using `$_REQUEST["email"]` as a filename without any validation is VERY, VERY dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an caching issue. Did you verify that the new picture is saved correctly on the server?

If the picture is saved correctly, then you should add some headers in the RetrievePic routine to prevent it from being cached. See also: [Disable cache for some images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728616/disable-cache-for-some-images)

Comment: Yes new picture is being saved on my server.

Answer (score 0):

- I don't recommend you handle files with its extension. **It can be camouflaged** easily.
  Also `$_FILES['UserPic']['type']` isn't dependable.
- Under PHP Version **5.4.1**, there are serious security holes concerning **$_FILES**.

  - Directory Traversal Attack
  - **$_FILES** Collapse Attack

You should do like this:

```
<?php

// Configure
$upload_key     = 'UserPic';
$max_filesize   = 2097152; // Bytes
$save_directory = '/home5/username/public_html/Project/Users/Images';

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.1') < 0) {
    die('This PHP Version has serious security hole concerning $_FILES.');
}

if (isset($_FILES[$upload_key])) {

    try {

        $error = $_FILES[$upload_key]['error'];

        if (is_array($error)) {
            throw new Exception('This script can\'t accept multiple files');
        }

        switch ($error) {
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                throw new Exception('Exceeded upload_max_filesize');
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                throw new Exception('Exceeded MAX_FILE_SIZE');
            case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
                throw new Exception('Incomplete file uploaded');
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                throw new Exception('No file uploaded');
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
                throw new Exception('No tmp directory');
            case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
                throw new Exception('Couldn\'t write data');
            case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
                throw new Exception('Extension error');
        }

        $name     = $_FILES[$upload_key]['name'];
        $tmp_name = $_FILES[$upload_key]['tmp_name'];
        $size     = $_FILES[$upload_key]['size'];

        if ($name === '') {
            throw new Exception('Invalid filename');
        }

        if ($size > $max_filesize) {
            throw new Exception(sprintf('Exceeded %d bytes limit', $max_filesize));
        }

        if (!is_uploaded_file($tmp_name)) {
            throw new Exception('Not an uploaded file');
        }

        $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
        $type = $finfo->file($tmp_name);

        if ($type === false) {
            throw new Exception('Failed to get MimeType');
        }

        if (substr($type, 'image/jpeg') !== 0) {
            throw new Exception('Only JPEG images available');
        }

        if (!isset($_REQUEST['email']) || !is_string($email = $_REQUEST['email']) || $email === '') {
            throw new Exception('E-mail address required');
        }

        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid E-mail address');
        }

        $new_name = $save_directory.'/'.$email.'.jpg';

        if (is_file($new_name)) {
            throw new Exception('The file already exists');
        }

        if (!@move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $new_name)) {
            throw new Exception('Failed to move uploaded file');
        }

        $msg = "File successfully uploaded as {$new_name}";

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        $msg = 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();

    }

} else {

    $msg = 'No file sent';

}

echo json_encode($msg);
```