# how to map image to image button in asp.net with session using c#?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, html

I have an image folder in my project solution. I capture the image for a customer and i keep it in it. After i fill the details I redirect to another aspx page and i take the pic and come back to registration page and map the image to an image button i am using session variable to map the image path which is in the image folder.  My problem is I get the same image even if i take a new pic. I am keeping jus one pic at a time in the image folder why do i get the previous image which is not in the image folder. Am i not supposed to get the new pic which i have taken? Please elaborate more on this and  provide me a solution..I would be grateful to you..

Comment: I think your browser is Caching the image.You must have written some logic to cache the image ..

Comment: I am using session state mode="Inproc" which mode should I use

Comment: inProc supports Session_OnEnd event write some logic to clear cache in this event...Well TGH has given a good solution.

Comment: thanx Talha Hanjra..I will try with the idea u gave..

Comment: I have given my session timeout as 20 mins...why do i get the same image even after 20 mins is over..Please throw more light on it

Comment: Kindly open incognito window and test the application ..Its purely CACHE problem.I will aslo suggest you what @TGH suggested below.

Comment: okay Talha i will do that

Comment: remember to vote answers and accept them..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot delete browsers cache programmatically however below code will help you for disabling caching and clears existing cache from your application... Caching is your problem as you explained in question.

```
public static void DisablePageCaching()
{
    //Used for disabling page caching
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be browser caching at play. One way to get around it is to add a random querystring param to the image url (a timestamp etc) to make the image url unique.

```
<img src="someImage.png?someParam=1234" />
```

Comment: is there any alternative other than this..please suggest me

Comment: There is an answer to a similar question here, assuming it's due to browser cache http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728616/disable-cache-for-some-images

Comment: Thanx TGH i will try with this logic

Comment: thanx TGH it was a caching issue in the browser