# What do the parameters/query string on an image mean?

Tags: html, image, parameters, query-string

I saw a few images on a certain site that linked images with a parameter.

Ex: Image was linked as `//s.cdn.foobar.com/images/foobar.png?3`. What does the `?3` signify on an image? I thought usually only normal HTML pages contain query strings. What is the point of having this query string on the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only use I know of for putting query strings on images is to prevent caching.  Some sites put a random value in a query string for this.

Here's an older question that discusses this [Disable cache for some images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728616/disable-cache-for-some-images)