# preventing caching on form submit

Tags: php, html, forms, caching, refresh

I have a form where I use php to write text to the form, everything works perfect, but most of the time the new texts which are written to the form field does  not appear unless I make some way for complete page refresh.

I tried it all on `addtext.php`

```
        header("Content-type: text/html");
        header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); 
        header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); 
        header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
        header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false); 
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        @session_start();
        ......
       <META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
       <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
       <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

from `addtext.php` so it is to another page

```
       form action  =addtext2.php?par=randomvalue
```

But still does not show the updated image, there is another function to cancel and bring on the original image from the original folder that also suffers but with less percentage from the cache issue

How Can I refresh the page and remove all cache

Many Thanks

Comment: may this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728616/disable-cache-for-some-images

Comment: Thank you, it worked like a charm: This is the approach:

<img src = 'myimage.jpg?someparmater=somerandomvalue'/> Worked like a charm, many thanks for your answer (y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution suggested by:

```
   http://stackoverflow.com/users/2097224/aldanux Worked like a charm, 

   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728616/disable-cache-for-some-images
```

many thanks aldanux

Thank you, it worked like a charm: This is the approach:

```
 <img src = 'myimage.jpg?someparmater=somerandomvaluegeneratedbyphp()'/>
```

Worked like a charm, many thanks for your answer (y)