# PhoneGap Images Update issues

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, cordova, caching

I am working on a project using Phonegap, i am creating profile page but the issue is that when user uploads new profile picture, picture successfully uploaded to the server, but it does not show updated picture in the profile, instead it shows the previous image, i know it is using the image from cache that was already there. So how can i avoid using the image from cache, i want new image from the server.
i used following code in ajax call but it is not working.
`cache:false`,

Comment: You could try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728616/disable-cache-for-some-images

Comment: that is a nice solution i will give it a try @Castillo