# Dynamically Created images is not showing properly

Tags: image, jsp, browser-cache

I am generating random number and creating image (in webapps folder) of generated number and after that this image is displaying on my jsp page.Problem is - if i reload browser within 1/2/3/4 seconds image is not changing on jsp page but in webapps folder image already changed. if i reload after 8/9 seconds it works fine.

Am i doing any theoretical mistakes?

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: May be browser cache is the problem try the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728616/disable-cache-for-some-images

Comment: Tried your quoted solution...same problem remain@KarthikeyanVaithilingam