# Gif is not working when the page is reloaded. Only works when the window is open for the first time

Tags: css, angularjs, html, gif

So, I have a gif which works fine if I load the website for the first time... but if I reload or go home, and then come back to that section... it displays the final Image (as if the animation already happened)...
The gif only plays once (it was created to animate only once). However, I believe it should play everytime the web is refreshed. How can I control that?

The code is simple

```
<div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
        <img src="images/unnamed.gif" id="gif" alt="">
</div>
```

I searched but couldn't find an answer. However, this gif is in an angular partial. And I belive that might be affecting it somehow. I created a random document in another project without angular and it works fine.... If anyone has a clue it would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `div` put a `ng-init="varname = 'images/unnamed.gif'"`. Then in your `img` element `ng-src="varname"`. This should override the original source attribute of the `img`.

My Code:

`<div class="col-xs-12 text-center" ng-init="varname='images/unamed.gif'">
        <img ng-src="{{varname}}">
</div>`

Comment: This is a very good one. However, if the ng-src needed to be changed inside an "if" condition... how could I access to it?

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
    <img src="" id="gif" alt="">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('gif').src = 'images/unnamed.gif?q=' + new Date().getTime();
</script>
```

This will prevent the browser from being able to cache the gif so it needs to load again every page load. It just sounds like some sort of either caching issue or something not set up properly when you created the gif.

Comment: THAT DID THE TRICK!!! I feel so stupid for not thinking about that earlier... Thank you so so so so much, I had a headache because of this!

Comment: Sure thing, glad to help!

Comment: Hey, not sure if I should do this here but... What you did, what does that do exactly? I mean, It indeed works awesome when reloaded but every single time I scroll the gif starts over

Comment: As I said, it prevents the browser from being able to cache the gif. Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/729623/2122300

Though I must say, if scrolling causes the image to load again, that makes things interesting. Does it do this in all modern browsers?

Comment: haha it's a pain, been in this for like... three days now. And yes, It happens in all browsers