# Java web application need to refresh to "see" resource files

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm working on a web based application with Spring MVC and Thymeleaf. I have form which upload image. I decided to save the images in `src/main/resources/static/images/` and that works perfect. But I found an issue with upload. When I save new image and try to display it in the HTML it's now working. When i refresh the `images` folder from STS and refresh the page it works fine. Can you give me some advice why this is happening and is there a way to fix it? I know i can use java code to get image content and display it as a resource but i would like to use thymeleaf's EL. I display the image with `@{/images/imagename.jpg}`

Best regards, 
Peter

Comment: Images are always cached by the browsers. This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728616/disable-cache-for-some-images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, if your resources are within your web app, you won't be able to display it and change it at will. When you refresh your `images` folder on STS, it "redeploys" the resources and you can see your images.

What you need to do is to put your `static/images` folder outside your web app, then you'll be able to easily upload a new image and have it displayed on your web app