# Angular img src binding and browser caching

Tags: javascript, angular, browser

I've noticed a strange behaviour in my angular 5 app in various places where I display images in the following way

```
<img src="{{user.avatar}}"/>
```

Chrome will show a picture of another user although when I console.log or debug the app the url printed is the correct one. When I change browser tab and return to the current tab, the correct image will load, which leads me to the assumption that this is a browser caching issue.

The behaviour is random and seems not to be happening in Firefox. I've also tried `<img [src]="user.avatar"/>`with the same results.

Also tried to add random dummy parameter on the src value to prevent the browser caching: `<img src="{{contact.userData.avatar+'?id='+randomId()}}"/>`
This seems to work but makes image loading pretty slow so I prefer to avoid it. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: can you share your code that assigns url to user.avatar?

Comment: unless you have differentiated urls this issue can hurt indeed. and your other solution (adding random numbers etc) seems like a thing unless you can play with headers...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728616/disable-cache-for-some-images

Comment: urls are coming from the server side and are of the type `http://localhost:8080/api/images/john.jpg` and `http://localhost:8080/api/images/mary.jpg`. I don't get why mary replaces john..

Comment: You could display the image URL on the page (e.g. `<div>{{user.avatar}}</div>`), and see if it is always correct. Since the URL is different for each user, I don't see why the cache would be a problem. It could be that the view is not refreshed at the appropriate time.

Comment: I did and it does print the correct url, even if I inspect the element from the browser it has the correct url. What could I try for changing the refresh interval?

Comment: So,the URL is correctly set to the image of `john` but you see the image of `mary`? I don't have an explanation for that behavior. And I don't understand why adding a random number to the URL makes a difference.

Comment: yes adding random number should help when url is the same. When its different - that's weird case indeed.

Comment: @Shakur can you still share more of the code snippet that replicates the problem?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko its not easy to isolate the issue but what I've noticed is that it only happens if the image has css styling. Tried to use [ngClass] to set the class dynamically but it still occurs

Comment: Can you share css block?

Comment: It's irrelevant, any kind of styling causes this