# Angular image source file change trigger bind

Tags: html, angular, image, ionic-framework

I have an image in my html : `<img height="40" src="{{Variables.path}}">`

I want to rebind the image file if the file is changed. But not the name of file, file's itself is changing with same name. I am recreating another image file with same name.

I want to rebind the image source to image an tried this to trigger bind event:

```
 var tmp = Variables.path;
 Variables.path = "";
 Variables.path = tmp;
```

Bu this is not rebinding image source.

I tried changing file name and it rebinds source. Like this :

```
Variables.path = "another.png";
```

But I should not change the file name. I can just recreate it with same name.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to related to cache of browser (or hybrid app). So solved by assigning random querstring to img source url :

Variables.path = "another.png" + "?query=" +  Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(5000));

[solved with help of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728616/disable-cache-for-some-images/729623#729623)