# Replace image with the same path not working after second time in Html/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an application in Asp.net Core MVC in which user upload his profile image. The server side is working fine but at client side when i change the image src for first upload, it works fine but after second time the image replaced at server but at client side it shows the same. That's how i am changing the src of an image.

```
var src = "/up_images/profiles/" + result.data;

 $("#profileImage").attr("src", src);
```

please note that i am replacing the existing image. In this case if src is "/up_images/profiles/137.jpg" then after uploading image the src will be the same. "137" is the user id.

if i refresh the page the image changes too.

also i have tried with some delay using timeout but it is not working.
What is the issue?

Comment: the function that calls the src needs to be refreshed or called again on the client-side if the path stays the same and just the image is being replaced on the server-side.

Comment: well, it is the callback of ajax and it calls every time when i upload new image.

Comment: possible to show a working snippet, so we can take a look at it?

Comment: If the file has the same path, it is being cached. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728616/disable-cache-for-some-images).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image path is exactly the same but resource changes, you'll want to force the request. That can easily be done by appending a query such as the current time.

```
$("#profileImage").attr("src", src + "?" + Date.now());
```

Or with template literals

```
$("#profileImage").attr("src", `${src}?${Date.now()}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try appending a query parameter that changes for each request, onto the end of the URL. It will get ignored by the server side, but the browser will treat it as a new request and not re-use the cached image.

Something like this:

```
var src = "/up_images/profiles/" + result.data + "?v=" + Date.now();

 $("#profileImage").attr("src", src);
```