# How to refresh a photo link reference when a component mounts in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a component like so:

```
export function SomeComponent(props) {
  const { id } = props;

  const photo = `http://someurl.com/photo/${id}/`;

  return (
    <View>
      <Avatar
        rounded
        source={photo}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

I have a photo update endpoint which updates the photo that is stored in `http://someurl.com/photo/${id}/`.

The issue is after the update and I visit the route where this component is shown, it's still showing the old photo. Only if I refresh the page, will the photo get updated.

Is there a way to force reload the content of the link? Or do I need to force reload the route that contains the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the page re-renders when the states or props are updated, you can manually trigger re-render by setting up a state or prop and changing its value.

one scenario:

```
ParentComponent() {
  const [trigger, setTrigger] = useState(false);

  const onUpdate = () => {
   setTrigger(false);  
 }
return (
 ..... your code 
 <SomeComponent trigger={trigger} />  // trigger is passed as prop so as its value changes component re-renders
  ) 
}
```

Comment: The page rerenders because other data are updated to the latest, but the photo link doesn't because it's storing the cached photo.

Comment: Avoid image cache if that is the case:

Comment: You need to add random query string with the url like this:

````<img src="image.png?dummy=8484744" />````

As provided in the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728616/disable-cache-for-some-images