# Disable image caching for StreamImageSource

Tags: c#, .net, maui, .net-maui

When I load an `ImageSource` from an `Uri`, I can disable image caching by setting the `CachingEnabled` property to false.

With an Image element in XAML

```
<Image x:Name="image"/>
```

the code below will load the image without any caching.

```
var imageUri = "https://www.google.de/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";

image.Source = new UriImageSource
{
    Uri = new Uri(imageUri),
    CachingEnabled = false
};
```

Now I want to do the same with a `StreamImageSource`:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();

image.Source = new StreamImageSource
{
    Stream = async cancellationToken =>
    {
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(imageUri, cancellationToken);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
};
```

There seems to be no property to enable or disable caching, and I would not expect any caching at all. But on my Android device, the application writes image cache files to a folder named `image_manager_disk_cache` in `FileSystem.CacheDirectory`, which can be reproduced by

```
var imageCacheDirectory = Path.Combine(
    FileSystem.CacheDirectory, "image_manager_disk_cache");

if (Directory.Exists(imageCacheDirectory))
{
    foreach (var imageCacheFile in Directory.EnumerateFiles(imageCacheDirectory))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(imageCacheFile);
    }
}
```

Sample output is:

```
[0:] /data/user/0/com.companyname.imagecachetest/cache/image_manager_disk_cache/journal
[0:] /data/user/0/com.companyname.imagecachetest/cache/image_manager_disk_cache/5bcc99fe6930c85add40cfc486ae9a5a0451c08d71c6d3cd679ea26ec0293b9b.0
```

How can I disable this image caching for StreamImageSource?

---

Edit: My guess is that this caching is performed by the `Glide` library, which is used by the imaging implementation of .NET MAUI on Android. I could however not find any information about how to disable Glide image caching in a MAUI application.

Comment: In order to disable the caching of pictures, it may be necessary to change the picture path. If pre caching is required, please set a variable to point to the path of the cached image. You may have a try first according to this idea. Or you may refer to this website:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728616/disable-cache-for-some-images

Comment: @HongxinSui There is no "picture path", just a Stream from which an ImageSource is created. Note that I am not asking about HTTP caching. The caching here is performed by the imaging implementation of .NET MAUI on Android, presumably the Glide library.

Comment: In that case, you may need to disable both hard disk cache and memory cache, please try to do like this: Glide.with(this)
        .load(imageUri)
        .skipMemoryCache(true) //disable memory cache
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE) //disable hard disk cache
        .into(imageView)  And I'm just suggesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: It seems to be fixed now, at least for `StreamImageSource`. See here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/13111

---

Looking through the .NET MAUI source code I found

[src/Core/AndroidNative/maui/src/main/java/com/microsoft/maui/PlatformInterop.java](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/9ded53385880238b0edcf3b643bb25a548e43a1f/src/Core/AndroidNative/maui/src/main/java/com/microsoft/maui/PlatformInterop.java)

with relevant methods shown below.

In `loadImageFromStream`, the `cachingEnabled` argument is always set to `true`. This seems wrong to me. I have created an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9773.

[Line 261](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/9ded53385880238b0edcf3b643bb25a548e43a1f/src/Core/AndroidNative/maui/src/main/java/com/microsoft/maui/PlatformInterop.java#L261)

```
public static void loadImageFromStream(
    ImageView imageView, InputStream inputStream,
    ImageLoaderCallback callback) {

    RequestBuilder<Drawable> builder = Glide
        .with(imageView)
        .load(inputStream);
    loadInto(builder, imageView, true, callback); // true seems wrong here
}
```

[Line 232](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/9ded53385880238b0edcf3b643bb25a548e43a1f/src/Core/AndroidNative/maui/src/main/java/com/microsoft/maui/PlatformInterop.java#L232)

```
private static void loadInto(
    RequestBuilder<Drawable> builder, ImageView imageView,
    Boolean cachingEnabled, ImageLoaderCallback callback) {

    MauiCustomViewTarget target = new MauiCustomViewTarget(imageView, callback);
    prepare(builder, target, cachingEnabled, callback);
}
```

[Line 214](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/9ded53385880238b0edcf3b643bb25a548e43a1f/src/Core/AndroidNative/maui/src/main/java/com/microsoft/maui/PlatformInterop.java#L214)

```
private static void prepare(
    RequestBuilder<Drawable> builder, Target<Drawable> target,
    Boolean cachingEnabled, ImageLoaderCallback callback) {

    builder = builder
        .error(callback);

    if (!cachingEnabled) {
        builder = builder
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
            .skipMemoryCache(true);
    }

    builder
        .into(target);
}
```