# How to force a web browser to cache Images

Tags: http, browser, caching, response

I am writing a small application which serves images from the local computer, so they can be accessed as http://localhost:12345/something/something (which returns a jpeg).

How can I force the browser to cache this, so only a single request would be sent to the server. Would this header be sufficient

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=99936000
Content-Length: 123456
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

This seems to work with Firefox 3.x but would it be sufficient globally for other browser as well?

Comment: Related: How to force a web browser NOT to cache images. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126772/how-to-force-a-web-browser-not-to-cache-images

Answer (score 17):

A [Last-Modified](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29) and [Expires](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21) header might also be useful additions.

Your server should also check for requests featuring an [If-Modified-Since](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.25) header, and return a 304 Not Modified response if possible to speed things along.

Answer (score 0):

try the expires http header: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers

You probably have to merge this with your cache-control

Answer (score -8):

You can't and nor should you - this is the user's decision to make not yours.

What you *can* do is strongly suggest with the right headers, but even then you should expect t deal with a number of HEAD requests ever after.

Comment: In some cases where bandwidth are an issue you should.

Comment: Responses where the responder suggests that you shouldn't be doing something, rather than answering the question.. are the most obnoxious. Add to that, that this is actually a reasonable question.

Comment: Try saying that when you have a gallery with 4.1 million images with links being shared all over different websites.