# forcing browser to cache images in php website

Tags: php, image, caching, browser, header

I've a php based website and would like browser to cache the images for 30 days .. i am using a shared hosting solution where I do not have access to apache config to enable mod-headers or other modules and so can not use htaccess mechanisms for this.

my site is a regular php app, and has both html contents and images. I would like browser to cache images only. I've seen php's "header" function, but couldn't find a way to force only image cache .. How do i go about it ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force a web browser to cache Images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285354/how-to-force-a-web-browser-to-cache-images)

Comment: Another Dupe: [How to get the browser to cache images, with php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385964/how-to-get-the-browser-to-cache-images-with-php)

Comment: Is that for HTTP/1.0 or HTTP/1.1 or both type of requests?

Comment: both .. does it differ ?

Comment: [Key Differences between HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1: Caching](http://www8.org/w8-papers/5c-protocols/key/key.html#SECTION00030000000000000000)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, if you can't get access to Apache to set the headers, your only other option is to serve images from a PHP script so you can use the PHP Header methods to set the headers.

In this case, you'd need to write a PHP image handler, and replace all your image tags with calls to this handler (e.g. http://mysite.com/imagehandler.php?image=logo.png). You would then have you imagehandler.php script retrieve the image from the file system, set the mime type and cache control headers, and stream the image back to the client.

You could write your own, or if you google, you will find image handler PHP scripts. Either way, make sure you focus on security - don't allow the client to retrieve arbitrary files from your web server, because that would be a fairly major security hole....

Comment: wow !  That would be too big a change .. btw, just by setting header cache age would cache the entire page ( including data ) ?

Comment: The HTTP headers apply to each request - so no, I don't think you can set the page to cache all it's children. 
Yes, it is a big change....