# How can I FORCE my web browser to cache images for testing purposes?

Tags: image, internet-explorer, caching, browser

I've got a bug report from the field that essentially boils down to image caching. Namely, an image from the same URL is getting cached and it's causing confusion because the image itself is supposed to change.

My fix is to do [this bit here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728616/disable-cache-for-some-images). Which I'm certain will work.

However - I can't freaking reproduce this. I would prefer not to do [the methods I've seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285354/how-to-force-a-web-browser-to-cache-images) because they require code modification and I'd rather test this on the code as it exists now before I test a fix.

Is there any way in a browser like IE to force it to cache like mad? Just temporarily, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Fiddler](http://www.getfiddler.com) to force things to cache or not to cache; just use the Filters tab and add a caching header like

```
Cache-Control: public,max-age=3600
```

You can have the customer use www.fiddlercap.com to collect a traffic capture so you can see exactly what they see.

You should also understand that the proper way to control caching is by setting HTTP headers rather than forcing the browser to guess: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/07/14/caching-improvements-in-internet-explorer-9.aspx

Comment: Not to sound dumb, but how do I set that in Fiddler?

Comment: Click the Filters tab. Scroll to the bottom. Tick the "Set Response header" checkbox. Put the name of the Header as Cache-Control and the value as public,max-age=3600