# MP3 Audio Caching on your Website

Tags: caching, web, mp3, autoplay

I have a client that wants to have music on their website and needs it to auto-play. I put a music player on the site and it works good randomizing between the 2 songs in the list. My problem is that they keep running into bandwidth issues. I need to find a solution in which the music player on the site will look for the cached file before trying to re-download it.

Is there a music player or code I can use that reads off of cached files? I've been looking for a bit and have been unable to find anything.

Or, is there an easier solution to my problem? (Other then taking music off the website, turning auto-play off, both of which I would prefer but am unable to do.)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple.  Include the correct caching directives with MP3 resources, just as you would any other file you want to have cached.

See also:  [How to force a web browser to cache Images](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1285354/362536)