# how can i load images from server and save into cache

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, offline-caching

I want to load images from server and want to save into cache.It means i want to load images from server one time and whenever i again want same image it should not be loaded through server for particular time. How can i do this into angular.The problem is related to image caching if one time image is loaded than it should be stored in the cache memory.
Example:- Suppose there are 4 user on portal and each user have their login i want to set cache storage time for each user how can i do this?

Comment: I guess your browser will automatically do it for you!

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10240297/4790490) post

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285354/how-to-force-a-web-browser-to-cache-images)

Comment: Yes, browser can done it but only one time i want to set the cache storage time for every user so every user able to see new images after some time.

Comment: How is this related to CSS?