# download.file() fails when appending a random suffix to the filename

Tags: r, caching, download, browser-cache

I'm trying to download a file in R on a remote server which sits behind a number of proxies. Something - I can't figure out what - is causing the file to be returned cached whenever I try and access it on that server, whether I do so through R or just through a Web Browser.

I've tried using `cacheOK=FALSE` in my `download.file` call and this has had no effect.

Per [Is there a way to force browsers to refresh/download images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431512/is-there-a-way-to-force-browsers-to-refresh-download-images) I have tried adding a random suffix to the end of the URL:

```
download.file(url = paste("http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/ftp/F-F_Research_Data_Factors_daily.zip?",
                          format(Sys.time(), "%d%m%Y"),sep=""), 
              destfile = "F-F_Research_Data_Factors_daily.zip", cacheOK=FALSE)
```

This produces, e.g., the following URL:

```
http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/ftp/F-F_Research_Data_Factors_daily.zip?17092012
```

Which when accessed from a Web Browser on the remote server, indeed returns the latest version of the file. However, when accessed using `download.file` in R, this returns a corrupted zip archive. Both WinRAR and R's `unzip` function complain that the zip file is corrupt.

```
unzip("F-F_Research_Data_Factors_daily.zip")
1: In unzip("F-F_Research_Data_Factors_daily.zip") :
internal error in unz code
```

I can't see why downloading this file via R would cause a corrupted file to be returned, whereas downloading it via a Web Browser gives no problem.

Can anyone suggest either a way to beat the cache from R (about which I'm not hopeful), or a reason why `download.file` doesn't like my URL with ?someRandomString tacked onto the end of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work if you use `mode="wb"`

```
download.file(url = paste("http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/ftp/F-F_Research_Data_Factors_daily.zip?",format(Sys.time(),"%d%m%Y"),sep=""), 
          destfile = "F-F_Research_Data_Factors_daily.zip", mode='wb', cacheOK=FALSE)
```

Comment: @Ina, [here is a blog](http://timelyportfolio.blogspot.com/search/label/french) that uses data from Kenneth French -- may be useful to see how he downloads the files.