# Images not changing on some computers

Tags: html, image, caching, magento-1.9

I'm having a little challenge here. After changing banner images on some part of my homepage, it the new images don't show even after clearing cache and re-indexing. Can someone please advise me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding a version number to the image path in your code, as detailed in this answer: [Is there a way to force browsers to refresh/download images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431512/is-there-a-way-to-force-browsers-to-refresh-download-images)

You just need to add `?1` at the end of the url like so:

```
<img src="image.png?1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens because you need to clear your browser cache on whatever machine you're viewing the site with - a fast and easy way to find out if this is the case would be to throw your browser into private/incognito mode and refresh the page.