# Heroku: The simplest application, could not find or load main class

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, heroku, deployment

I after having troubles with deploying my app on Heroku, I created the simplest application possible: it contains two files: an `index.jsp` and a `SomeServlet.java`.

I have the following **project structure**:

```
TestDeployApp
  --WEB-INF
    --classes
      --com
        --web
          --SomeServlet.class
    --web.xml

  --src
    --com
      --web
        --SomeServlet.java

  --target
    --classes
      --com
        --web
          --SomeServlet.class
    --dependency
      --webapp-runner.jar
    --maven-archiver
      --pom.properties
    --gs-serving-web-content-0.1.0.jar
    --gs-serving-web-content-0.1.0.jar.original

  --index.jsp
  --pom.xml
  --Procfile
  --TestDeployApp.war
```

**index.jsp**:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>it's a jsp</body>
</html>
```

**SomeServlet.java**:

```
package com.web;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.*;


public class SomeServlet extends HttpServlet {
            public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
                    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
                    out.println("<html><body><h1>" + today + "</h1></body></html");

            }
}
```

**web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">

    <display-name>TestDeployApp</display-name>
    <description>
        This is a simple web application with a source code organization
        based on the recommendations of the Application Developer's Guide.
    </description>

    <context-param>
            <param-name>adminPlanet</param-name>
            <param-value>Earth</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SomeServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.web.SomeServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SomeServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/SomeServlet.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-serving-web-content</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <start-class>com.web.SomeServlet</start-class>
    </properties>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>

                            <artifactItems>

                                <artifactItem>
                                        <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                        <version>8.0.30.2</version>
                                        <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>

                            </artifactItems>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
        </plugin>


        </plugins>

        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Procfile**:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes/:target/dependency/* com.web.SomeServlet
```

What I'm doing to deploy it all:

```
git init
git add 
git commit -m "first"
git push heroku master
heroku open
```

After the browser window opens I see `An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.` error.

In logs:

```
2018-02-10T20:16:50.864803+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class com.web.SomeServlet
2018-02-10T20:16:56.052981+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes/:target/dependency/* com.web.SomeServlet`
2018-02-10T20:16:58.391978+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-02-10T20:16:58.419611+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-02-10T20:16:58.099331+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2018-02-10T20:16:58.103410+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
2018-02-10T20:16:58.297295+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class com.web.SomeServlet
2018-02-10T20:17:41.405484+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=testdeployapp-mine.herokuapp.com request_id=c217c572-e92a-409d-b8c8-27e57bb20013 fwd="178.217.106.173" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-10T20:17:42.829328+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=testdeployapp-mine.herokuapp.com request_id=21b0276c-ef8c-41b0-92c1-86c15d727aad fwd="178.217.106.173" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-10T20:17:58.784267+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=testdeployapp-mine.herokuapp.com request_id=a303e9da-e9d5-4d15-bd78-d3de2b3b3240 fwd="178.217.106.173" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-10T20:18:12.634882+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=testdeployapp-mine.herokuapp.com request_id=ce575c1b-d1ab-4f83-aaf7-a95cab4c7752 fwd="178.217.106.173" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I also then tried to use `java -jar webapp-runner.jar application.war` command, but I get an `Unable to access jarfile webapp-runner.jar` error in cmd.

Any suggestions are welcome. I tried all the variations of **Procfile** I could find, nothing seems to work.

Comment: browser caching?

Comment: Try with incognito tab

Comment: Some browsers have a "disable cache" option available when the developer tools are open

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to force browsers to refresh/download images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431512/is-there-a-way-to-force-browsers-to-refresh-download-images)

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you are mixing the `war` or "web application" deployment with `jar` or "executable" deployment. For the first one, you need to have a Web Application which can be deployed on the Servlet Container like Tomcat and the package in `.war` format. For this type of deployments, Heroku will require you to run your application via providing `target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar` to [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile). So the idea behind it is to ask Heroku to run servlet container and deploy your `.war` file.
So you will need to change your Procfile to

`web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war`

But as I see you are using the Spring Boot packaging, which creates a `jar` packaged executable with the embedded servlet container. But you do not have any main class which will start-up spring boot application. So in your case just add a spring boot main class like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And then change your Procfile to
`web: java -jar target/your-app-name.jar`

So either change the application type from Spring Boot to a usual web application and use Heroku web runner or add Spring Boot starter main class.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your java classpath is not correct?

java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes/**:target/dependency/*** com.web.SomeServlet

Answer (score 0):

Is your port number correct while you are trying to access the app? Check your default port once. Might be `localhost:8080` or other which you are not aware of.