# Add a revision number to images in symfony to avoid browser cache

Tags: css, image, symfony-1.4, browser-cache

I would like to avoid browser cache on my images by appending the SVN revision number after each images like this (in the same fashion than [this answser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/126831/311744)):

```
<?php $v = getRevisionNumber() ?>
<img src="picture.jpg?v=<?= $v ?>" alt="">
```

Is there a way to do it automatically in Symfony 1.4 ([like this](http://www.lampjunkie.com/2008/05/append-revision-number-to-css-and-js-includes-in-symfony/) for js/css, but with images instead)

Also, how can I do it for an image that is in a css file ?

```
#title {
    background-image: url(/images/title.png);
}
```

Comment: Hmm... overriding the `image_path()` in the `AssetHelper` would what you're asking for those called from your template files.  Are you asking for a config in some yml file setting somewhere to that will append a suffix like you're asking?  The Css though I'm not sure.  May have to add your own custom parsing.  image_path source: http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/helper/AssetHelper.php#L299

Comment: What do you mean by `May have to add your own custom parsing.` ? What I would like is to append a parameter on every image (called with image_helper or without php, as in the css example I gave) .

Comment: Well you can dynamically generate your CSS with a PHP script, rendering a page with `header('Content-type: text/css')`, would probably be how you would do it.  You could, with this script, read the CSS and then parse and filter it with your requirements.  Perhaps someone else could provide a better solution?  +1 Good question

Comment: @YzmirRamirez My project is quite big, that would mean renaming quite me lot of css files and changing a lot of images paths. That's what I am trying to avoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something interesting in the symfony tracker, for the version 1.3/1.4, there were a patch to automatically add a timestamp to all files in the web directory: http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/6135

It has been reverted since, no idea why ... (to intrusive?).

### Override the default asset helper

Anyway, I think you have to create your own AssetHelper (copied all contents from the current one) and add & customize the patch #6135 into a `lib/helper/CustomAssetHelper.php`.

But you can't unload the AssetHelper because it is automatically loaded in the core: http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/view/sfPHPView.class.php#L33 So there will be conflict since you will have duplicate function (in AssetHelper and CustomAssetHelper).

### Add a custom *template engine*

The idea is to have a custom `sfPHPView` to redefine the `loadCoreAndStandardHelpers` to call your own asset helper (put it in `lib/view/sfCustomPHPView.class.php`):

```
class sfCustomPHPView extends sfPHPView
{
  /**
   * Loads core and standard helpers to be use in the template.
   */
  protected function loadCoreAndStandardHelpers()
  {
    static $coreHelpersLoaded = 0;

    if ($coreHelpersLoaded)
    {
      return;
    }

    $coreHelpersLoaded = 1;

    $helpers = array_unique(array_merge(array('Helper', 'Url', 'CustomAsset', 'Tag', 'Escaping'), sfConfig::get('sf_standard_helpers')));

    // remove default Form helper if compat_10 is false
    if (!sfConfig::get('sf_compat_10') && false !== $i = array_search('Form', $helpers))
    {
      unset($helpers[$i]);
    }

    $this->context->getConfiguration()->loadHelpers($helpers);
  }
}
```

To change the default sfPHPView, you need to add a `module.yml` in `config/` or `apps/frontend/config/` with the following contents ([inspired from sfTwigPlugin](https://github.com/henrikbjorn/sfTwigPlugin/blob/master/doc/01-Introduction.markdown)):

```
all:
  view_class: sfCustom
```

### Override all `image_tag()`

As *Yzmir Ramirez* said, `image_tag()` calls `image_path()` which call `_compute_public_path($source, 'images', 'png', $absolute);`.

In `_compute_public_path` function, before the last condition, you customize the query_string to add your own revision number (which will be define somewhere else - sfConfig for example):

```
$file = sfConfig::get('sf_web_dir').$source;
if ('images' == $dir && sfConfig::get('my_revision_number'))
{
  $query_string .= sfConfig::get('my_revision_number');
}
```

It might be a bit complex but using this way, you can override image_tag function and add the version number you want without redefine all you image_tag() call.

About image inside a CSS, it's a bit more complex since you will have to parse css or write css in PHP. No idea about the best way to do.