# PHP URL string to avoid browser caching

Tags: php, caching

My site is designed to be a funny picture site, when the user hits the random button a PHP code on the same page generates a new random picture, this is how it is supposed to work. I however have to hit the F5 button to get a new image.

I was reading on another question that people use a get date and get time query string generated at the end of the link to avoid browser caching, I however can not figure it out for the life of me.

I am not very good with php so please speak as if I only know the basic webpage structure. Thank you!

Comment: you better to set headers, than use that 'trick'

Answer (score 6):

What you are describing is called a cache breaker and is usually a random string or a timestamp appended to the url. When you are referencing your image, prepend it like this:

```
echo get_random_image_url() . '?' . time();
```

This will result in an url looking like this:

http://your.server.com/random.jpg?1355862360

Note: `get_random_image_url` is just an example, but i'm sure you get the idea.

This thread may be of interest: [How to force a web browser NOT to cache images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126772/how-to-force-a-web-browser-not-to-cache-images).

Comment: its actually referencing a php file that pulls a random funny image from my hosting. I am sorry, i am pretty good with CSS and html but i just started learning a few months ago. Any more help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

i think using headers is better than the url trick

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Great and can i place this anywhere in the webpage structure? ex. head, body

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to be solved: for example,
Check the following two links:

http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/06_Place_20773_1_Mis.jpg

http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/06_Place_20773_1_Mis.jpg?randomValue

Both of the two links will be open the same image.

This is your solution! You have to add at the end of your image file name a random value:

```
image.png?<?php echo someRandom();?>
```

This community or Google for a way to write a function that gemnerates random values.

Also there is solution using [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), suupose the following

```
<img id="funny" src="scripts/php_rand_image.php" />
<a href="javascript:changeImage('funny')">Get another image</a>
<script>
function changeImage(ob){
image = document.getElementById(ob)
d = new Date();
image.src = image.src+'?'+d.getTime();
}
</script>
```

Comment: i attempted your response because it seemed to be the easiest, thank you, but when i put that at the end of the URL, ex:"<a href='http://coolexample.com/index.php?<?php echo someRandom();?>'><img src="http://coolexample.com/random.php" width="540" ></a>" in the index.php file the page no longer displays. Any feedback?

Comment: You have to notice that: someRandom() is a custom function that you have to write. The someRandom() should be suffixed to the image url. In the other hand, I recommend to use the Javascript dependent solution.