# How to avoid cache on PHP redirect with location?

Tags: php, html, caching, redirect

I have a little web with two files: a `index.html` that only shows a
image and a link to the second file named as `change-image.php`.  The
latter contain a form to upload a new image file to replace the image
showed by `index.html`. It also process the form, renaming the new
image to `image.jpg` and redirecting to `index.html` to show it.
Looks like:

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'image.jpg');
    header('Location: index.html');
    exit();
}

echo <<<END
...
   <form action="change-image.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
...
END;
```

The problem is that i get the same first image. Then I need to use the
refresh button on browser to view the new image. Curiously if i
repeat the action the script starts to work fine without refresh
required until new browser restart (tested in firefox and chrome).

Comment: I think you're saying `image.jpg` is changing and the browser should be loading that a second time, but in reality it is loading it from the cache. In that case, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126772/how-to-force-a-web-browser-not-to-cache-images

Comment: The problem is very similar but i can't change the filename for the image. I have simplified the problem in order not to extend the question. The filename actually is a hash of a user name and the image is its avatar so must be constant.

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox I beg your pardon. After closer inspection, your suggestion might work for me although i don't like it very much. It produces ungly urls ;-)