# Load very large number of images into one webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to load 5000 images into a webpage, each image has a size of about 120KB.
The images are displayed as thumbnails inside a scrollable , and at any time there will be 16 visible images inside that 
I tried to use Lazyload jquery library but my problem is that the cache of the browser is getting full quickly.
Is there any way for loading large number of images without over filling the cache?
Thank you in advance
Rami

Comment: Check out [jQuery infinite scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/)

Comment: using a lazy-loading plugin is a very good idea for this usecase. You can set the header to "no-cache" to controll the client behaviour. Maybe take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728616/disable-cache-for-some-images beside the accepted answer you could use the answers that define http headers

Comment: To prevent caching load the images with a fake querystring `"MY_KITTEN.JPG?random12345DateTimeEtc"`

Comment: @AlexK won't that just lead to have `MY_KITTEN.JPG?random12345DateTimeEtc` been chached? Or will images with query string never get cached? This is usefull if you have dynamically changing images with the same filename, but i don't know if a page full of these won't result in a full cache as well.

Comment: @NicoO Thank you for your answer, I just tried it out and it didn't work, the browser is still crashing after a while. I don't know how to verify if my problem is in caching or in something else then. I am using Chrome and I don't know how to check if the crash is caused by a full cache now.

Comment: @NicoO No, a browser should understand the content of an object with a querystring should not be cached http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126772/how-to-force-a-web-browser-not-to-cache-images

Comment: @Rami have you tried the solution with the query string in the file name also? I'am not sure how browsers behave with these. Definitely worth a try.

Comment: Thank you @AlexK. interessting topic

Comment: what is the point of preloading if don't cache? the problem is that you have to many elements on your page, much less <img> elements, and much less 120kb images at that...

Comment: My I ask why you need to load 5000 images in one page?

Comment: @NicoO, no querystring does not implicitly prevent caching.  It will stop the browser from reading from cache when the querystring changes randomly but the cache is still written to.  Use headers to prevent caching.  That said, browsers don't crash when cache becomes full... Rami's problem lies elsewhere

Comment: Dear all, indeed as @RobertLevy mentioned, aparently my problem is somewhere else. The propositions of Nico and Alex are valid. I believe that my issue lies in resizing the images to fit the thumbs. Thank you all for your propositions.