# After changing a Video, Chrome keeps playing the old one

Tags: html, google-chrome, caching, html5-video

```
<video control src="video.mp4"></video>
```

Now replace the *video.mp4* **file** with an other videofile with the same name (*video.mp4*) and reload (*f5* or *ctrl+f5*).

Chrome keeps playing the old "video.mp4"

There is no traffic at all in the network console.

Can someone tell me what's going on?

How can i force Chrome to check for changed files without renaming the file?

Comment: Clear your caches from browser and cache purged from server

Comment: The server doesn't get hit. This happens local too, no need for a server setup. Anyway, I can't force my users to clear always their caches if they visit the page.

Comment: What cache headers are you sending?

Comment: It's not cache header related - it happens local without a server. Just open a plain html file in chrome. Looks more like the client/browser is caching it and don't refetch the video if the name doesn't change

Answer (score 2):

3 years later, but this issue still exists. Quick fix for those who end up on this question as I did, just change the name of the video. This is going to force Chrome to reload and play new one

Comment: Yes - and same solution.

Answer (score 0):

[@mark-nugent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24532641/13775586) worked perfectly for me :

Basically the idea is to "**affix a unique query string to the end of the video file so the browser reloads it** -- easiest is to **use a time stamp** like so :"

1- if your page is a **HTML page**, use Javascript :

```
<video control src="video.mp4"></video>
<script>
   var video = document.querySelector('video');
   video.src += '?' + new Date().getTime();
</script>
```

In this code, we select the video element and append the current timestamp to the end of its src attribute. This updates the URL of the video file to include the timestamp, which forces the browser to reload the video when it is played.

2- if your page is a **PHP page**, it's even simpler, use the `filemtime` function :

```php
<?php echo "<video control src=video.mp4?" . filemtime('video.mp4') . "></video>"; ?>
```