# Chrome not re-requesting source when running video.load()

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, html5-video

My chrome browser doesn't seem to re-request the videos source once you run video.load().

```
<video class="player" controls muted autoplay>
    <source src="/createReadStream" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<script>
    const video = document.querySelector('.player');

    video.onended = () => video.load();
</script>
```

Im changing the video that is sent back from the server every 10 seconds and I just need the browser to re-request the video after it has played it, which works fine like this in Firefox but not in Chrome as it isn't re-requesting the source. I've found this through the dev-tools networking tab as there is no new request going out in Chrome but there is in Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been observed elsewhere that Chrome will not re-request a video file if the name has not changed - see this question for example and there were some Chromium issues I believe too: [After changing a Video, Chrome keeps playing the old one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52278136/334402)

One way to verify this is the issue and also to workaround the problem is to  either change the name each time, by appending a number for example, and have your server just delete the appended number.

Alternatively, and easier if it works for you, you may be able to just add a random query parameter, or a sequential number, to the URL which your server can just ignore - e.g.:

```html
<video class="player" controls muted autoplay>
    <source src="/createReadStream?_n=000001" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested code, but this might "trick" the Chrome browser. Let me know how it goes:

```
<video class="player" controls muted autoplay>
    <source src="/createReadStream" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<script>

const video = document.querySelector('.player');
video.onended = () => resetSource();

function resetSource()
{
    //# first set a dummy "src" value... then set correct URL
    video.src=""; video.src="/createReadStream";
    video.load(); video.play();
    
}
    
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply; I've tried this and it doesn't work for me unfortuantly