# Script to redirect if connection is established

Tags: javascript, html

I have made this script that, if I have internet (checking with image) then it redirects, but it keeps images in cache, and if I have no internet then it still loads.

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/image.png"
   onload="window.location='http://www.example.com/index.html';"
   onerror="window.location='error.html';" 
width="0px" height="0px"><br>Loading...
```

The problem is the cache, it caches the image and then when I reload without internet it still tries to load. Does anyone know another way to fix it?

Comment: to avoid cache, you have to use an other url, like add a random GET parameter at the end., see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126772/how-to-force-a-web-browser-not-to-cache-images

Comment: `http://www.example.com/index.html?1` is also a valid URL which points to the same index.html

Comment: it must only be Javascript and HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this :

```
<body onload="myimg.src='http://www.example.com/image.png?'+(+new Date())">

    <img id="myimg"
       onload="window.location='http://www.example.com/index.html';"
       onerror="window.location='error.html';" 
       width="0px" height="0px">
</body>
```

The point is to add a random/unique value at the end of the url so the request is never the same

Answer (score 0):

Append a random number to the img url so that the browser doesn't cache the image. See

[Disable cache for some images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728616/disable-cache-for-some-images)