# How to make an image update on screen if the filename does not change?

Tags: html, image, caching

I have an image

```
<img src="whatever.jpg">
```

An AJAX request uploads a different image to the server, replacing the file. When reloading I can see the new image.

**How to make the image show the new file without reloading the page?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126772/how-to-force-a-web-browser-not-to-cache-images) inspired a simple solution; add a timestamp to the query string of the src attribute when uploading the file with success.

```
<img src="whatever.jpg?2874652">
```

Which will cause browsers to reload the file from the server.