# How can I load images without browser cache in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, browser-cache, image-upload

I'm developing one application in cakephp, in that when users upload their profile pictures, different type of thumbnails will be created. If users again change their profile picture, then the new picture is not shown the website unless 3 to 5 times refreshing the website.

How can I load images without browser cache in cakephp?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force a web browser NOT to cache images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126772/how-to-force-a-web-browser-not-to-cache-images)

Comment: Designing the app such that the url changes if the content changes is the "better" idea -> no hacks required.