# How to clear application cache programmatically using ionic/cordova?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am building an application of photo editing, where I use several images. Generally cordova camera or image picker plugin returns absolute image paths. I am working with those image paths, but it has a disadvantage. The application cache storing all image paths, and its going to larger day by day. I want to build a functionality where, just after editing the image, I will upload it into server and after successful upload, automatically clean the cache. But I am not finding any option to clean cache programmatically. I tried to use Cordova filetransfer plugin also. But it has not effect. Anyone please tell me, how may I do it.

Thank you in advance for you attention.

Comment: Try something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126772/how-to-force-a-web-browser-not-to-cache-images)

Answer (score 0):

[The reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126772/how-to-force-a-web-browser-not-to-cache-images) @Korte gave you, has there a good solution how to avoid image caching.

If you are looking for a way to clear the WebView cache in a Cordova Application, I would recommend using the [cordova-plugin-cache-clear](https://github.com/anrip/cordova-plugin-cache-clear).

To use the plugin in your code, simply call `window.CacheClear(success, error);`