# How can you update a picture on a website without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a program that saves a .png file in a certain folder, the image that it is taking is always the same name, so every time it deletes the old picture and replaces it with a new picture.
I want my website to display the images as they created, The problem is the website only shows the first image and not "refreshing" the website so I always see the same image.

The program that is saving the picture is written in Python and the image name is image_request.png, I tried adding time at the end of the file name but it didn't work out, I also tried adding a sleep function same result...

This is the Html+js code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="side">
<h2>Live camera:</h2>
<img id='img' style="height:150; width:300;" src="/static/image_request.png" onload="updateImg()">

<script type="text/javascript">
  function updateImg() {
  newImage = document.getElementById('img')
  while(true) {
  newImage.src = "/static/image_request.png"
  console.log('done')
  }
}
</script>
</div>
</div>
```

If I run it, I see one picture And the whole website freezes...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force a web browser NOT to cache images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126772/how-to-force-a-web-browser-not-to-cache-images)

Answer (score 0):

There are two immediate issues here:

- You're trying to re-request an image at the same URL, which won't prompt a reload.
- You're using a `while(true)` loop without no exit condition.

I'd be surprised if the code you provided *wasn't* freezing your website. A `while(true)` loop will run *thousands* of times per second. Within 30 seconds, the browser will choke and either crash the tab or lock up the browser entirely.

What you're more likely looking for, instead of a while loop, is some sort of cache-busting mechanism.

---

## Timestamp

The simplest way to fix this would be to set up your web browser to serve the image at a static URL, then update the URL on your client with the current timestamp tacked onto the end as a query parameter. For instance,

```
const elem = document.getElementById('img');
const url = "/static/image_request.png";
setInterval(function(){
    // e.g., static/image_request.png?r=1566576298288
    elem.setAttribute('src', `${url}?r=${new Date().getTime()}`);
}, 10000);
```

With this code, every ten seconds, the browser will update the URL with a new timestamp on the end; this should prompt the image to reload. If you've set up your server correctly, the query parameters won't affect where you look for the file, and it should return the content of the static URL.

As an aside, you really shouldn't do this frequently, as it will likely cause the image to disappear briefly while it is being loaded. For periodic refreshes, though, it should work fine.

---

## Websockets

You might find the above solution perfectly workable for your needs, but I do want to briefly elaborate on a better, but more involved, solution.

Instead of hard-coding the image path, you could use WebSockets to open a persistent connection between the client and the server. Each time an image changes on the server, it could broadcast the encoded content of the image to all clients through the socket connection.

When a client receives a socket message from the server, it could update the URL of the image with the encoded content directly, without having to make another request to the server.

This method would save you from having to deal with reloading one persistent file path, and also eliminate any flashing or vanishing when the image is reloaded. This method would also allow you to switch from using an `img` tag to a `canvas`, which might be better depending on your exact needs.