# Fix The Css and Assets to display in repository

Tags: css, github, repository, assets

Hei there, why my css and assets not show when i upload in github, but in local host css and my assets display, how to fix this problem? because i find cant have the asnwear about this problem

please tell me about the answear

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Are you asking about why your CSS and assets aren't uploaded to GitHub Pages, or why they aren't used there, or why the HTML as rendered on github.com doesn't use your CSS?

Comment: You may want to read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is caused because github caches some files, give a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126772/how-to-force-a-web-browser-not-to-cache-images).